# system of equations word problem (explanation please)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

so I have the question "Michael is 3 times as old as Brandon. 18 years ago, Michael was 9 times as old as Brandon. How old is Brandon now?"

To put it into an equation: $$m = 3b$$ $$m - 18 = 9(b-18)$$
Now I don't get why we multiply 9 times the -18 (as in 18 years ago) to get a correct solution here. Can someone explain the logic behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Age of Michael $18$ years ago) is $m-18$

(Age of Brandon $18$ years ago) is $b-18$

(Age of Michael $18$ years ago) = $9$ (Age of Brandon $18$ years ago)

$(m-18) = 9 ( b-18)$

Comment: Didn't really answer my question, thanks though.

Comment: Maybe your question is not clear enough... I would have answered the same.

Comment: That is the meaning of "18 years ago, Michael was 9 times as old as Brandon" Michael was younger $18$ years ago, same thing applies to Brandon.